# QMultiHash insert() behavior for duplicates

Tags: c++, qt, data-structures, qt4, hashtable

I have a `QMultiHash<Key, Value*>`.  I may have more than one `Value*` per `Key` so I do want to store every `Value*` that corresponds to each `Key`, but I don't want to store exact duplicates where `key1 == key2 && value1 == value2` more than once.

If I call `QMultiHash::insert( Key, Value* )` with a `Key/Value*` pair that is already in the hash, will it add a second copy?  In other words, if I call `insert()` multiple times with the same `Key/Value*` pair, and then call `QMultiHash::values( Key )` will I get back the same `Value*` once, or will I get a list with the `Value*` occurring the same number of times that I called insert?

Comment: Why not give it a try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. [`QMultiHash`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmultihash.html), by definition, allows multiple values associated with a given key. That's the "Multi" part of the `QMultiHash`. For example,

```
QMultiHash<int, int> multi;         //multi.size() = 0
multi.insert(5, 1);                 //multi.size() = 1
multi.insert(5, 2);                 //multi.size() = 2
QList<int> list(multi.values(5);)   //list = {2, 1};
```

If you want to enforce unique keys, you should use QHash to communicate this fact to other programmers and check ['QHash::contains(key)'](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qhash.html#contains) prior to insertion. Also note that insertion order matters!

Similarly, `QMultiHash` allows duplicate key-value pairs, not just duplicate keys. For example,

```
QMultiHash<int, int> multi;         //multi.size() = 0
multi.insert(5, 2);                 //multi.size() = 1
multi.insert(5, 2);                 //multi.size() = 2
QList<int> list(multi.values(5);)   //list = {2, 2};
```

If you want to allow multiple values with a single key but still enforce unique key-value pairs, you have to manually check for the unique pair prior to insertion using [`QMultiHash::contains(key, value)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmultihash.html#contains).

Both of these facts are intended features in Qt, putting the burden on the programmer to enforce uniqueness instead of taking a performance hit doing that check with every insertion. This is what a C++ programmer should expect from a well-designed class.

Comment: Can you please clarify on the duplicate/unique keys?  There really is no such thing as duplicate/unique keys since the keys themselves aren't stored in the hash.  They are used as look-up values.  I think I know what you mean and if so, I agree with you.  I just want to make sure we are technically correct so we don't confuse anybody in the future.  If you want me to just edit your answer I'm happy to do so

Comment: Since the question seems to be asking about the functionality of the class QMultiHash, I am speaking to the functionality of QMultiHash::insert, not the underlying implementation of it. If the question is asking about whether multiple copies exist in-memory, then it should be edited.

Comment: I have edited my answer to clarify my meaning regarding duplicate/unique keys.

Answer (score 0):

No, you will not get back the `Value*` only once.  You will get back one copy for every time you called insert.  `QMultiHash::values( key )` will return a `QList<Value*>` that contains the same number of duplicates as calls to `QMultiHash::insert()`  This was determined by running a test to see what would happen.